# How to get the row information from a google form grid item

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I created a form with google scripting and now I want to retreive the responses. The example from [google](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-response) is working fine but I also want the row information from the grid item.
In the [information](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/grid-item#getrows) I should be able to use getRows, but it's not working. What I'm a doing wrong?

```
 function checkForm(){
var form = FormApp.openById('formId');
var items = form.getItems(); 
for (var i in items) { Logger.log(items[i]);
  Logger.log(items[i].getTitle() + ': ' + items[i].getId() + '-' + items[i].getType() +' -');
    if(items[i].getType() == "GRID") 
    {Logger.log(items[i].getRows());}
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
if(items[i].getType() == "GRID") 
    {Logger.log(items[i].asGridItem().getRows());}
```